# Can you get silent sign in with Facebook Comments plug embedded in a UIWevView in a iOS app?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

We use Facebook Comments in an UIWebView in an iOS app. Over 50% of our users are signed in with Facebook into our app so we have an access token for that user.

It seems crazy that when we load the FB comments plugin in the UIWebview in our app, that the user needs to re-authenticate.

Is there a way to leverage the fact that users may have already authenticated with our app and silently sign in them in with their access token? I expect to find some way of passing an `access_token` parameter to the comment plugin but don't see anything in the docs.